# I need to solve this equation: 2 cos^2 θ − 7 cos θ − 4 = 0 on the interval 0 ≤ θ < 2 π

Tags: trigonometry

I've been trying to solve the problem, but I keep getting errors.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi Uzmatic, welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. It would be helpful if you could expand on what you have tried so far, and what kind of errors you are getting.

Comment: Hello there, I put in

Comment: Reduce[{2 (cos^2) [\[Theta]] - 7 cos[\[Theta]] - 4 == 0, 
  0 <= \[Theta] <= 2 pi}]                     and that didn't work

Comment: i get the error: " This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce."

Comment: Please add this to your question! Thanks!

Comment: `Reduce[{2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 - 7 Cos[\[Theta]] - 4 == 0, 
  0 <= \[Theta] <= 2 Pi}]` yields `\[Theta] == (2 \[Pi])/3 || \[Theta] == (4 \[Pi])/3`

Comment: Hello, I would like to give credit to both of you guys. I'm new to this website and don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is relatively simple - just some syntactic errors.

You say that you tried the following:

```
Reduce[{2 (cos^2) [[Theta]] - 7 cos[[Theta]] - 4 == 0, 0 <= [Theta] <= 2 pi}]
```

The correct syntax for this is:

```
Reduce[{2 (Cos[t]^2) - 7 Cos[t] - 4 == 0, 0 <= t <= 2 Pi}]
```

and the result is

[image: result]

It would be a benefit to you to read at least the [Fast Introduction for Math Students](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/). Hope that's helpful.

Comment: thank you, and I'll look into the intro you linked

Comment: Also, `Solve[{2 (Cos[t]^2) - 7 Cos[t] - 4 == 0, 0 <= t <= 2 Pi}]`